# Pass config variables from package.json to Browserify

Tags: node.js, browserify, package.json

Is it possible to pass defined in 'config' section of package.json variables to browserify? All is running from 'script' section such:

```
"config": {
    "API": "somePathToAPI",
    "port": 9999
},
"scripts": {
    "prewatch:js": "browserify app/js/app.js -o out/bundle.js -d",
    "watch:js": "watchify app/js/app.js -o out/bundle.js -v -d",
    "start": "npm run watch:js"
}...
```

The idea is to pass both API and port variables to Browserifys environment (for example proccess.argv or process.env properities accessible from window object).

I'm not sure if it's important but I try to achieve this on Windows 7 machine.

Or maybe this approach is wrong and You use some other technics to store Yours config variables?

Answer (score 0):

All values in your `package.json` are exported to the environment. The variable names should be `$npm_package_config_API` and `$npm_package_config_port`.

You can see all the exported variables by running `npm run env`. *(Depending on your version of `npm`, you may need to add the `env` script yourself: `"scripts": { "env": "env" }`)*

You can even override the variables in scripts too, by prefixing them with your package name and the variable's name. Check out the examples here: [NPM Config Variables](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/#npmconfigvariables)

You might also want to check out [Per-Package Config Settings](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#per-package-config-settings).

If you're just looking for a transform to keep the environment as literals in your code, checkout [`envify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envify).

Comment: using the `$` prefix for variables such as `$npm_package_...` in npm scripts would work only in linux based environments. Conversely, on Windows, one would need a `%~, e.g. %npm_package_...%. To support both OS types, use [run-script-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)

Answer (score -1):

there is no way to access them in clientside js code, but on serverside code:

```
var port = process.env.npm_package_config_port;
var api = process.env.npm_package_config_API;
```

EDIT: You could create a cookie with `port` and `API` server-side and send it to the client.

Comment: Oh bummer, I thought that there is a way. I noticed some advanced flags in Browserfiy such as '--insert-global-vars' or '--detect-globals' but I doesn't work for me :-/